# Angularjs ui grid has poor resolution on ipad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, retina-display

I am using angular-ui-grid (http://ui-grid.info/). Version 3.1.1.
When it is displayed on the computer screen, it displays clearly. When I load it on the ipad it looks blurry. I think it is something to do with the retina screen. Is there any way to fix this so that the text in the grid displays clearly?

UPDATE: I am not sure if it is to do with the retina screen. On a Mac with retina display, it seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out. I used the following meta tag on the page and it looks a lot nicer.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
```